# How can i get to do this jquery submit synchronous?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, asynchronous, submit, blueimp

This is the submit. I need the result of operation, but this is async....
form.data(); contains data for the upload. i'm using blueimp JQuery File upload...

thanks....

```
$('#formFileupload').data().submit();
```

Comment: How do you submit a form asynchronously? Not sure the question is very clear?

Comment: does .data() contain a submit method? By default it does not.

Comment: See [this](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). Try to implement handler, like submit(function() { ...your code... }), it could get you close to what you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14896151/1414562  could be good reading

Comment: Kevin, the data of form, is load on fileuploadadd event of fileupload..... $('#formFileupload').data(data);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `sequentialUploads`:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
         ........
         sequentialUploads: true,
         .......
         .......
})
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn autoUpload off, collect the files in an array, then on form submit do a single ajax call with all the files together with the form data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566501/335396).